# Is there a way to disable the workspace switcher in unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the Workspace Switcher launcher from Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-unity-launcher)

The workspace switcher is not a regular  launcher and not a lense but there must be a place where the panel gets it (and the trash) and where I maybe can easily unregister it???