# Can I move the workspace switcher icon to the top of the Unity launcher

Tags: unity, workspaces, icons, dock

I would like to move the Workspace switcher icon from the bottom to the top of my Unity dock bar. Is this possible? Drag and drop does not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: Only for Unity 2D

**Not for Unity (3D)**, not without modifying the source code. For Unity 2D, see @Matt2's answer just above or below this one.

If you want to modify the source code, download `unity` and look at `plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherController.cpp`. I don't know the exact changes required, but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/80608/58612) which talks about modifications to `LauncherController` to *remove* the Workspace Switcher should give you some good hints.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Hope it gets implemented in the short future. For now I will stick to Super+W or hot corners in CCSM.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/761155

There is a workaround for unity2d as described at http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/10/customizing-unity-2d-ubuntu-natty.html

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml
```

find this section:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
  items.appendModel(bfbModel);
  items.appendModel(applications);
  items.appendModel(workspaces);
  items.appendModel(devices);
  items.appendModel(trashes);
}
```

You can rearrange these.
Please remember that this fix only works with Ubuntu 2d

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I use Unity in my systems...

Comment: Although the bug link says unity-2d, reading the comments reveals that it also affects unity, so keep an eye on it.  Sorry there's no easy workaround for this.