# How can I disable the workspace-switcher on the Sidebar?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the Workspace Switcher launcher from Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-unity-launcher)

I dont use the Workspace-Switcher on the Sidebar but I'm not able to remove it. I tried it with MyUnity, Unity Tweak Tool, ... but there is no helpfull option. Perhaps you can help me?