# How do I remove the workspace switcher from the Unity dock in 12.10?

Tags: unity, icons, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the Workspace Switcher launcher from Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-unity-launcher)

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-unity-launcher) was the go-to way to do this prior to 12.10, but in 12.10 you don't have the plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherController.cpp file anymore.

Any way to do this in 12.10?

Comment: I've added a 12.10 answer to cover this.