# Desktop Switcher like MacOS or PearOS 7?

Tags: 12.04, unity, .desktop

I saw the Desktop Switcher in PearOS like this:

[image: Desktop Switcher in PearOS screenshot]

Can I have the same in my Ubuntu 12.04? I installed a PearOS, but I find no name to this Desktop Switcher.

Thank for help.

Comment: For what desktop environment?  Someone could certainly put one together with minimal effort, but it might behave differently on different DEs.

Answer (score 0):

The Pantheon Desktop from [Elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In unity:
You can switch workspaces with then new icon on the launcher or ctrl+alt+arrows

[image]

[Since 13.04 it is disabled by default.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260510/how-do-i-turn-on-workspaces-why-do-i-only-have-one-workspace-in-13-04)
You can enable it as follows (ubuntu 13.10):

1. Click on the settings/shutdown button on top right
2. Click on system settings
3. Appearance
4. Behaviour tab
5. Enable workspaces