# shortcut to change workspace 13.04

Tags: 13.04, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Until 13.04, I could change my workspace using ctrl+alt+arrow but since 13.04 it is impossible.

Is there a way to have a shortcut back?

Comment: Duplicate question: [How do I turn on workspaces?](http://askubuntu.com/q/260510/52726)