# Why Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Down won't move a window one workspace down in 13.10

Tags: shortcut-keys

I tried to move a window one workspace down using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> keyboard shortcut. It didn't work. I could get it to go left and right, but not down.

How can I fix this?

It seems the down arrow does not work at all (unless if I am in a word processor or Internet browser).

Comment: [The bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/ubuntu-settings/+bug/1241282) is invalid on launchpad, so the question is not off-topic.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu actually is "Fix released" so, the bug was valid and solved, just that didn't affect Saucy. BTW, changing the status yourself isn't so reassuring.

Comment: @Braiam Ok, you can consider it a bug, I will consider that the shortcut in 13.10 has changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed in an ubuntu session (unity

*Fixed in 14.04*, may be backported to 13.10, may not

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-settings/+bug/1241282

Also the default does remain the correct bindings & can easily be reset in ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) > wall > bindings > move with window within wall & clicking on the little x on far right to reset to default

[image: ccsm]

Answer (score 24):

That's not a bug, it's because in 13.10 the default shortcuts for moving a window one workspace down or up changed to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> respectively:

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: [How to turn on multiple workspaces](http://askubuntu.com/a/287408/18533) ...