# How do I move a window to another workspace in Ubuntu 18.04 using Gnome Classic and the mouse

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, mouse, workspace-switcher

Have installed Ubuntu 18.04.05 and Gnome Classic.
If I right click a gnome terminal, I can move the Window to another workspace.
If I right click nautilus or gedit, this option is not available.

Is there a trick to move those and other windows to other workspaces.
Should this not be considered a bug?

I absolutely hate the Ubuntu One interface, so I do not consider that an option.

Comment: if you have multiple workspaces enabled you can use Ctrl+Super+Page-uo (or Page-down) to move the window in focus up or down a workspace as required. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/362070/307670

Comment: I have multiple workspaces. The "Move to workspace <directions> is set to 
Shift-Super-{PU,PD} or Shift-Ctrl-Alt-{Left,Right}, but that is using the keyboard. I would like to use the mouse. 
When I type Alt-Space I get the mouse menu for moving to another workspace, but not if I simple right click on the Window.

Comment: Is this regression intentional?