# Appearance option in System Settings suddenly gone

Tags: unity, 14.04, workspaces, system-settings, appearance

Recently, volume and sound stopped working. Soon after I [lost the ability to go into System Settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505631/gnome-control-center-cant-be-accessed-by-unity-search-sound-devices-not-recogn) other than through the console. Then many of my launcher icons vanished. Now my workspaces have become disabled and I can't find [the Appearance app from which to re-enable them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260510/how-do-i-turn-on-workspaces-why-do-i-only-have-one-workspace). How can I access Appearance so I can get my workspaces back?

On a related note, are my troubles Ubuntu's fault or is there something I'm doing that's causing the problem? I don't know of anything that I'm doing other than automatically installing updates. I haven't manually `apt-get installed` anything recently, either. I would normally assume that these problems were abnormal and my fault, but others in my department are experiencing similarly frustrating interface problems (e.g., workspaces breaking, windows becoming inaccessible, etc.); quite frankly, we're all getting good and fed up with Ubuntu 14.04's apparent instability.

Comment: What hardware are you using, and can you open the appearance app with `unity-control-center appearance`? And do the settings launchers exist in `/usr/share/applications/`? Also, are you using PPAs / unoffical software

Comment: How can I tell you the hardware that I'm using?

Comment: what computer make/model, cpu & graphics etc from `lspci -v`, posted in a comment.

Comment: The whole output is here. I'm not sure what specifically will be of use, so I haven't omitted anything:  http://pastebin.com/J0mTB9uq

Comment: I am also unable to use `gnome-control-center appearance` (unity-control-center doesn't exist on my machine). There is no launcher for gnome-control-center or anything similar. The full list of those is found here: http://pastebin.com/ztteXs9f