# Can't find Workspaces

Tags: 14.04, workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I cannot find workspaces.  I have done searches in the Dash for it, I have tried 'sudo apt-get install workspaces' in a terminal.  All without success, help required!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to "Appearance" -> Behavior tab and click enable workspaces.
You can find it more detailed here:
[How do I turn on workspaces? (Why do I only have one workspace?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260510/how-do-i-turn-on-workspaces-why-do-i-only-have-one-workspace)

Comment: Thanks, I did do searches on the subject but I obviously didn't ask the right question.