# two terminals in different workspaces

Tags: 14.04

I would like to have two terminals running in different workspaces.  What I want to do is having python2 and python3 running at the same time.  Is this possible ?  I'm using 14.04.

Comment: sure, but not sure what you mean; two terminals with a different python interpreter in each terminal?

Comment: Yes, just open them and drag to different workspaces.

Comment: You may have to enable workspaces first, please read [How do I turn on workspaces?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/260510/how-do-i-turn-on-workspaces-why-do-i-only-have-one-workspace)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
Open the terminal in a workspace using the shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Switch the workspaces using

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>

Again Open another terminal using the same keys or
if you have opened two terminals in the same workspace, you can switch to other workspaces using the shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>