# Why are workspaces disabled by default?

Tags: workspaces, development

In the recent versions of Ubuntu, workspaces are disabled by default. Is there a specific reason for this.

I know how to [enable them](https://askubuntu.com/q/260510/184942), but I wish to know the reason why the developers choose to disable them by default.

Comment: Speculation: because most people do not use them and because it could be considered an advanced feature. By the way: we do NOT have workspaces anymore; we have viewports (a workspace would be a table top where 4 workspaces equals to 4 tabletops. 4 viewports are ONE tabletop where you have 1 area of 1 tabletop active.

Answer (score 5):

The workspace switcher is disabled by default in Ubuntu 13.04, according to feature request.

Please see following [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/868423) for explanations

> This change request is now summarized in a google doc, see
>   https://docs.google.com/a/canonical.com/document/d/1cbPd9WSSbFHg4Z7BSOQxDKusMe2aJjj0FEF2AMxNOZM/edit#
>
> ----------------------------------------- Workspace switcher should not be in the Launcher by default.
>
> - The workspace switcher should not be in the Launcher by default (both on fresh installs and upgrades)
> - Dragging and dropping the workspace switcher into the Trash should remove the icon from the Launcher and disable workspaces
> - It should be possible to drag and drop the workspace icon to place it into any position in the Launcher
> - If the workspace switcher is not present in the Launcher, all other workspace functions and touchpoints on the desktop should be disabled.
>     These touchpoints are:
>
> -- The Alt+Space window accessibility menu
>   -- The 'right click on window title bar' menu
>   -- The workspace shortcuts listed in the SUPER key keyboard shortcuts overlay
>   -- All workspace related keyboard shortcuts

Comment: It probably will attract more upvotes if you would include some of the arguments/rationales from the link.

Comment: This doesn't have an explanation why as much as a description of the feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is **for people who have no idea of concepts such as workspaces**.

> Have you ever seen a new user accidentally switch workspaces and become totally lost?
>   Besides, it's easy to turn them back on if you know how to use them.
>
> https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1dc6z2/why_are_work_spaces_disabled_by_default/

Comment: Since I use an external monitor, I don't use workspace anymore