# why does grsync not appear after launch?

Tags: unity, grsync

I finally got grsync installed and set up several jobs, one specifically to back up a lot of files before I leave home to travel. Has been working fine.

Now, in the middle of getting ready to leave, I can't use it.

The icon appears in the launch bar, but when I click it, it doesn't appear on the desktop so I can't execute a job.  Any of its jobs.  I simply can't see it.

When I click alt-tab to cycle through open apps, it appears in sequence normally.  But when I click on its image in that context, the same thing happens -- nothing appears on the desktop for me to execute a job.

Has this happened to anyone, with grsync or other apps, and what is a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered me same problem. After activating the multideskop /multi workspaces ([How do I turn on workspaces? (Why do I only have one workspace?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260510/how-do-i-turn-on-workspaces-why-do-i-only-have-one-workspace)) in Unity, the GRsync Windows appears, on an another desktop. And I can move it to my main desktop.

Comment: Thanks, Genma!  Just enabling workspaces allowed it to appear.  Still have to learn more about how to work with them, but at least now I can back up my machine.