# How to create workspaces in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, workspaces

How can you create and enable workspaces in Ubuntu 20.04. I can't seem to find the option to make them and enable them in GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 10):

I would advise to install gnome-tweaks to manage desktops

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

I'm also using the extension Workspaces to Dock: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/427/workspaces-to-dock/

It makes switching between workspaces really easy!!