# Is there a way to bring up two or more windows (same app or not) when any of the them is switched to through Alt + Tab?

Tags: windows

Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome Desktop 3.36.8.

Suppose I have only one monitor, only one workspace and I am currently working on three windows of three different applications, App1, App2 and App3.

`App1`'s window is maximised and therefore takes up the entire display.
`App2` and `App3`'s windows are arranged in optimal sizes so that they do not overlap each other.
.
Whenever I have to switch from `App1` to either `App2` or `App3` I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to bring up their windows so that they are visible on top of `App1`'s window.

So my question is: can I group `App2` and `App3` windows so that when I switch to any of them I get the group of windows raised together on top of the other remaining windows?.

Comment: Would GNOME Extension `ShellTile` not perform that for you? [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. ShellTile looked promising, I installed it as a Firefox extension but it seemed not to be working on on my Gnome Desktop 3.36.8. The behaviour I get is exactly the same without ShellTile.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly where the dynamic workspaces fit in on the standard Ubuntu Desktop with Gnome Shell: visually separating different application, i.e. your two arranged windows from a full screen application.

Just put App2 and App3 on a separate desktop. When you switch to either of them, you will see the two applications as you wanted, just by a regular <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch or a click on the launcher's icon. *Problem solved.*

And yes, you need to use the workspaces to achieve that. *Embrace them.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any native way. But if it's always the same windows you want to group/focus you can add custom key shortcut to run a script to focus one or more windows, I do this to quickly set focus to apps even if they are on different workspaces.

e.g. simply using window titles with `wmctrl`:

`/usr/bin/wmctrl -a Firefox`

or

`/usr/bin/wmctrl -a "Google Chrome"`

See `man wmctrl` for more options.

Answer (score 0):

None of us can help you without knowing your version of Ubuntu. I didn't use Ubuntu/Lubuntu/Xubuntu for long time. That's why I don't think my answer will helpful or not. [image]. Workspace depends on gnome version also. You can change gnome version also. Here's [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236209/1166068) which may help you. [How to check gnome version?](https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-check-gnome-version.html). If you visit [the link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu&iax=images&ia=images). Than, you will see that there's two type of desktop in Ubuntu not only in Ubuntu either. Some has workspaces Some hasn't... And, if you are facing issue with shortcuts than, you can add shortcuts in settings..
[image]