# How to remove workspace switcher icon from launcher without disabling workspaces?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

I use multiple workspaces, but only through the keyboard commands, so the workspace switcher icon is just taking up space on the launcher for me. Ways of removing it (moving to the trash, checkbox in the appearances menu) also disable workspaces, which I don't want to happen. Can I keep workspaces enabled, but remove the icon?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I used alt+F2 > dconf-editor.
In the "com.canonical.unity.launcher.favorites" field, I removed 'unity://expo-icon'

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'd upvote if I could, but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: Now that I know what the setting name is, I see that another related question had an answer to my more specific one -- http://askubuntu.com/a/286344/189435