# Additional Workspaces

Tags: workspaces

Since upgrading to 13.10, am I now limited to just 4 workspaces?  Do I have to network two computers to get the 6  workspaces I had been using 13.04?  Or is that only available with a 32 bit system instead of 64?

I've been looking at other distros that do have multiple workspaces, but they lack the software I use most.

If the additional workspaces will no longer be available, I may have to back up to 13.04 and stay there.

Comment: in my 13.10 installation (64 bit) I am able to get more than 4 workspaces (using unity tweak tools). also if you want Ubuntu but not unity you could install other desktop environments, they also change the workspace behavior

Comment: in xubuntu you can get up to 100 ws

Answer (score 65):

9 workspaces for you

```
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize 3
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 3
```

:)

Comment: These are 2 command-lines to use with the terminal; first line to get 3 workspaces vertically and the second line to get 3 workspaces horizontally, so 9 workspaces. If you want only 6 workspaces, change the vsize and hsize values.

Comment: Best solution and by far. works on a wide variety of ubuntu versions (just did on a 12.04), does not need to install anything, clear and concise. @w_e_b , my vote is yours !

Comment: @w_e_b: will this work for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Did also work for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Also works perfect on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, thanks.

Comment: Worked nicely for me on 16.04. Note that obviously the workspaces icon in the launcher bar will stop being able to show you which ws you're on as it can only handle 4.

Comment: Thanks, a fine addition to my ubuntu-setup.sh :). Less work after formatting. P.S.- setup script is in Mega(like google-drive), so never lose it.

Comment: In addition, you can easily remove the workspaces icon from launcher by following these instructions:


https://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/how-do-i-add-and-remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-the-unity-launcher


`Super+S` performs the same action, displaying all of your workspaces.


Of course; `Ctrl+Alt+Left`, `Ctrl+Alt+Right`, `Ctrl+Alt+Up`, and `Ctrl+Alt+Down` arrows, perform the switches without displaying them via `Super+S`.

Comment: Just to update: works in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Another note: Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior -> Visual Effects must be set to High

Answer (score 13):

[Unity Tweak Tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool) will let you go up to 6 workspaces easily.

Just go to `Workspace Settings` under `window Manager` here you can set how many horizontal and vertical workspaces you want in the grid.

Comment: Not sure why, but last time I tried to install this, it did nothing.  This time, it worked fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I will assume by WORKSPACES you mean "virtual desktops"

You can easily set these in CompizConfig

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then

```
ccsm
```

Navigate to "General Options"

Select Desktop Size. Boom!

Comment: ubuntu seems to call 'virtual desktops' 'workspaces' for example the 'workspace switcher' in the launcher

Comment: I have changed the value here and it doesn't change the number of workspaces I have