# How can I remove the workspace switcher icon from Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspace-switcher

Is it possible to remove, hide or disable the following icon **but keep the workspace switcher feature enabled**?

[image]

Comment: `System settings > appearance > behaviour` unselect `enable workspaces`

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: wish that came before!

Comment: Apologies that I had forgotten to mention it!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/how-do-i-add-and-remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-the-unity-launcher?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `dconf-editor` ... to install it - execute : `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

Then open `com` -> `canonical` -> `unity` -> `launcher` and click on `favorites`

[image]

In the field `Custom value` remove `'unity://expo-icon',` and click `Apply`

[image]

Switch between work spaces with key combination : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow-Key</kbd>

When you want to revert the change, you have two options, either re-add  `'unity://expo-icon',` to `Custom value` or switch `Use default value` to `ON` and then click on `Apply`.
Note : the second option reverts **all** launcher icon setting changes back to default though.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Does this exist on Ubuntu 12.04?