# How do I remove the workspace switcher from the unity launcher in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: launcher, 20.04, workspaces

This question is similar to the aim of the following question:

[How do I add and remove the Workspace Switcher launcher from the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/how-do-i-add-and-remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-the-unity-launcher)

However the answer given by pepper_chico (and other answers) no longer works on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I attempt to reach `com.canonical.unity.launcher.favorites` I discovered I can only get to `com.canonical.unity` as there is no folder/directory/option of `launcher` only `lenses`

This was tested on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You just want to remove icon but keep workplaces, right?

Comment: Correct - Workspaces will be accessed by keyboard shortcuts

Comment: @KaiTheLynx Did you install Unity on Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @PRATAP No it was installed by default. It may not even be true Unity but a basic storage site for these configurations